# Networkx drawing bipartite graph

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, graph, networkx

I have two arrays  where there is a one-to-one mapping between the entries, I want to plot this as directed bipartite graph.

```
a = [1,2,3,4];
b = [4,3,2,1];
B = nx.Graph();
B.add_nodes_from(a, bipartite=1)
B.add_nodes_from(b, bipartite=0)
nx.draw(B, with_labels = True)
plt.savefig("graph.png")
```

But my figure is not proper.  How can I get well aligned figure with proper directed edges.

Comment: You need to add the edges and set nodes' coordinates.